# Passing data from view to controller in URL with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have a view, in which I want to, on the push of the button, send data to a specific function in a controller, which would then manipulate it a little and pass it forward to another view.  However, whenever the button is pushed, the screen is blank.  The URL changes to the correct URL, but in Chrome Dev Tools it gives the:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

error.  I am not sure what is failing to load, or what is going on.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

My view(the relevant part):

```
<script>
    $('#begin_practice').on('click', function(){
      location.href= "<?php echo base_url() . 'test/setupTest/' . $test_id . '/' . $lang . '/' . $practice; ?>";
    });
</script>
```

My controller (the relevant function):

```
public function setupTest($test_id, $lang, $practice){

  $this->load->model('Test_model');
  $test_key= ($practice) ? $this->Test_model->getKey($test_id, $lang, $practice) : $this->Test_model->getKey($test_id, $lang, $practice);

  $data['test_key'] = $test_key;
  $data['test_id'] = $test_id;
  $data['lang'] = $lang;
  $data['practice'] = $practice;

  if($practice){
    $this->load->view('tests/test_sample/' . $lang . 'practice_test_view', $data); 
  }else{
    $this->load->view($lang . '/test_view', $data);
  }
}
```

My model:

```
public function getKey($test_id, $lang, $practice){

  if($test_id == 7){
    $image_array = ($practice) ? $image_array = file_get_contents('<?=base_url();?>files/json/task_' . $test_id . '_practice_' . $lang . '.json') : $image_array = file_get_contents('<?=base_url();?>files/json/task_' . $test_id . '_' . $lang . '.json');
  }else{
    $image_array = ($practice) ? $image_array = file_get_contents('<?=base_url();?>files/json/task_' . $test_id . '_practice.json') : $image_array = file_get_contents('<?=base_url();?>files/json/task_' . $test_id . '.json');
  }
  $image_array = json_decode($image_array, true);
  if($test_id !=8){
    shuffle($image_array);
  }

  return $image_array;
}
```

If anything else is needed, please let me know.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using a button to replicate the behaviour of an anchor, can't you just make the anchor look like a button?

Comment: If you dump and kill the controller at the begining is anything actually being output? Isolate where the error is coming from. Could it be an issue with using the php short tags in the model? `<?=`

Comment: @Bankzilla  It does not seem to be getting into the controller at all.  Anything I try in the controller does not work.

Comment: What does the url before the redirection and after look like? I'm also assuming that `setupTest()` is within the Test controller?. If you go to `domain/test/testsetup` does it throw errors?

Comment: Also don't use camel casing for controller methods, I believe CI doesn't support this by default, you can test it by renaming the method `test_setup` and trying again

Comment: This line `$test_key= ($practice) ? $this->Test_model->getKey($test_id, $lang, $practice) : $this->Test_model->getKey($test_id, $lang, $practice);` is sufficient because in both cases same result will be returned from model.

Comment: @Bankzilla If I go to the url directly, I get the same errors.  Also, I changed the name of the controller to remove the camel casing, and there was no effect.

Comment: @Tpojka I noticed this as I was cutting and pasting the code onto here, but thanks for the advice!

Comment: What are the urls before and after redirection.

Comment: Also if you don't have error reporting turned on, then please do so.

Comment: @Bankzilla  Before the redirection, the url is from the previous controller, so it's site/testDelivery, and after the redirection it is site/setupTest/1/practice/1

Comment: The error_reporting is turned on to E_ALL

Comment: If you aren't even making it to the `setupTest()` method you have problems else where, I mocked up a quick demo, on all that's needed for it to work, so I'm not sure what you're doing.... http://pastie.org/private/7vvwlurcxlczhsz1sumoa